# Kaa hostname resolve failed

Tags: kaa

I've installed Kaa platform on Ubuntu 16-04. not Sandbox but source 0.11

> Default sample period: 1 seconds
>
> 2016/11/25 2:31:25 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:870] (-101) - Kaa TCP channel new access point [0x929A2016] hostname resolve failed
>
> 2016/11/25 2:31:25 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
>
> 2016/11/25 2:31:25 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0x929A2016] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure
>
> 2016/11/25 2:31:25 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:268] (-7) - Failed to connect channel [0x9E010CC0]
>
> Sampled temperature: 29
>
> Sampled temperature: 30
>
> Sampled temperature: 30
>
> Sampled temperature: 29
>
> Sampled temperature: 25

What are my errors indicating?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible reasons for such output:

```
   1. you are trying to run application without running/connected server.
   2. wrong server ip set in the web UI.
```

Things to fix:
1. check connection beetween kaa client & server then regenerate SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Perform these two steps may be this can solve your problem.

1. Just run this command on host machine

   sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh $*new host name/ip*$
2. Then change the IP address of using Admin UI, for that you need to sign in using username : kaa
   and passwword : kaa123

then go to setting > general setting then change the IP address preceded by :8080, enter your machine's public IP address, that can be easily  accessible from anywhere.

Tips :: if you are using AWS instance then use public IP address of your instance.

Further error persist then drop your previous instance and launch a new instance.

For more details go the [official documentation page](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Getting-started/#networking)

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured my kaa's host name to be my current connection's ip address because i am using bridged adapter as one of my methods of getting the new host name

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with KAA installation on my virtual server. Instead of putting the IP address inside `kaa-node.properties` just put the full domain name or hostname.

```
transport_public_interface=<server name or full domain name>
```

and on your client host, update DNS or `/etc/hosts` accordingly.

The client app will not complain about a name resolution issue.